# Delphi XE6 MessageDlg not listening to key click

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

in Delphi XE6, with the code below,
the first MessageDlg does not close while hitting the enter key (it does with mouse click) while the second MessageDlg shows normal behavior.

Very annoying behavior, at a very basic level. Can anybody shed light on this, and propose a workaround ?

```
procedure TForm20.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);  
begin  
  messagedlg('xxxx', mtError, [mbOK], 0);  
  messagedlg('xxxx', mtError, [mbOK], 0);  
end;
```

Comment: What happens if you move the MessageDlg calls to a procedure that you invoke by posting yourself a custom message in `FormActivate`?

Comment: Focus is on the OK button? (Possibly related: https://toom.wordpress.com/2007/02/14/messagedlg-change-default-button/)

Comment: Is it the same if you use `MessageBox`?

Comment: Btw, the reason I asked is that FormActive occurs while the current form is changing state, and that's not a good place to be displaying another newly-created form, which is what MessageDlg does.  That may be what has prompted @LURD's query.

Comment: @MartynA, yepp. Delaying the call or go straight to the OS are probably good workarounds.

Comment: Switching focus while the focus is switching can be problematic and is discouraged. You can insert an Application.ProcessMessages before calling the dialogs as a workaround. Of course moving the dialogs to elsewhere is suggested.

Comment: In my experience the observed behavior is a bug in XE6, this behavior was not there in earlier Delphi versions (haven't used them all btw). Inserting application.processmessages definitely solves the strange behavior, so I am happy ! @MartynA: in my experience FormActivate should better be called FormActivated, or DoAfterFormActivation because when entering it, all visual controls are drawn, all event handlers operational etc. So, I think the current form is not changing state, it **has** changed state when entering the FormActivate method.

Comment: @Mr. Nope. What application.processmessages does is to process the messages that would complete focus transfer, that's why it works. The form is still changing state.